# Update self referencing columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which data is something like this. Column `HOD` and `Reporting` are foreign keys are self referencing keys. While inserting data user added `EmpCode` in HOD and Reporting column instead of `ID` because at that time IDs were unknown because data was in Excel format. Now the data looks like this.

```
ID      EmpCode    HOD        Reporting
1       2          21         21
2       21         240        240
3       240        2          2
```

I want to write an update query that will update `HOD` and `Reporting` columns values with IDs, it should look at the `EmpCode` which is saved in the `HOD` and `Reporting` columns and get ID from that row and replace `EmpCode` with `ID`. For instance `HOD = 21` and `Reporting = 21` should be replace with 2 because `EmpCode 21` has the `ID = 2`.
I don't mind if I get 2 queries to get this done. There's is lot's of data so I cannot do it manually.
After updating the data it should look something like this

```
ID      EmpCode    HOD        Reporting
1       2          2          2
2       21         3          3
3       240        1          1
```

I have tried this query but it doesn't help

```
UPDATE HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo SET HODEmployeeCode = (SELECT ID FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo I WHERE I.HODEmployeeCode = tbl_EmployeeInfo.EmpCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE EI1
SET HOD = EI2.ID
FROM HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo  EI1
JOIN HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo  EI2
ON EI1.HOD = EI2.EmpCode
```